# How to fix version conflict detected for Microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.language?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created this web app a little while ago. I was able to get it running on my laptop and my roomates computer but when I try to open and work on it in school I keep getting this NU1107 error saying there is a version conflict. Does anyone know the fix for this?

Bellow is the error message

Suppression State
Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue. 
 CVGS -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.1.4 -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.4 -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 2.1.4 -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.4 -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core 2.1.4 -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating 2.1.4 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language (>= 2.1.1) 
 CVGS -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language (= 2.1.0).   CVGS    G:\cvgs-iteration_1\CVGS\CVGS.csproj    1

Answer (score 3):

Try to install .net core 2.1 SDK

Comment: thanks. it solved my issue with the same error on the build server.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar problem [consolidating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui#consolidate-tab) my projects in solution with nuget.

My problem was that I had dependencies in different versions in the solution that referenced each other.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you don't have the right SDK installed on the PC, It sounds like the package you are trying to install is expecting asp.net core 2.1.4 but couldn't find core 2.1.4 in the pc. Please download and install 2.1.4 from the following link

https://dot.net

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error if you are trying to Publish it to upload it to server
and you have selected SelfContained in the Deployment setting. Try Framework Dependent and it may go away.